# how to get the value of one js functions from one file to another js file

Tags: javascript, function

- i am new to js
- i am trying to get the value of  js functions from one file to another js file
- providing code below
- can you update my code

  file1.js
  function fileOne() {
      return value1;
  }

  file2.js
  function fileTwo() {
      /* pass value of fileOne function */
  }

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Comment: ` var val = fileOne();

    fileTwo(val) { alert(val); }`

Comment: Are both these files being loaded in a html/php file?

Comment: @JoseRodrigues in a html file

Answer (score 0):

In your html file make sure you have both js file loaded before you refer to the functions you are trying to use.

First load files

```
<script src="file1.js"></script>
<script src="file2.js"></script>
```

Then call functions

```
<script>
     var returnOne = fileOne();//call function from file1.js
     fileTwo(returnOne); //call function two from file2.js
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply...can you give an example using name space

Comment: You would create the namespace inside of file1.js and file2.js to keep functions from file2 overwritting functions from file1.  look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/881556/4825796 for more